# How to access syntax-class attributes in `~optional` that contains ellipsis?

Tags: racket

## TL;DR

I'm trying to expand an optional ellipsis `(~optional datum:my-class ...)` into a form that uses attributes from `my-class` like so: `#'(list datum.attr ...)`.

But as the form is optional, when it's not present, it resolves to `#f`, which the ellipsis pattern doesn't like:

```
;; ?: attribute contains non-list value
;;   value: #f
```

I tried using the `#:defaults` argument of `~optional`, like so:

```
(~optional datum:my-class ... #:defaults ([(datum 1) null]))
```

```
;; which works for usage:
#'(list datum ...)
;; but not for:
#'(list datum.attr ...)
```

I got it to work by using this trick:

```
(~optional datum:my-class ...)

#'(list #,@(if (attribute datum) #'(datum.attr ...) #'()))
```

I'm trying to find if there's a better way.

## Complete runnable example

I tried keeping it to the bare minimum. Check out the test submodule.
To see the issue, uncomment one of the four implementations of `parse-bag`, and run `raco test file.rkt`.

```
#lang racket/base

(provide parse-bag)

(require
  (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse)
  syntax/parse)

(struct bag (label objects) #:transparent)
(struct object (name) #:transparent)

(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax-class obj-exp
    #:datum-literals (object name)
    (pattern (object (name <name>:str))
             #:with result #'(object <name>))))

;; IMPLEMENTATION ONE
;; DESC: The naive but failing approach
;; UNCOMMENT TO TEST
#;(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
      #:datum-literals (label objects)
      [(_ (label <label>:str)
          (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)))
       #'(bag <label>
              (list <object>.result ...))]))
;; ?: attribute contains non-list value
;;   value: #f


;; IMPLEMENTATION TWO
;; DESC: adding defaults will fail too
;; UNCOMMENT TO TEST
#;(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
      #:datum-literals (label objects)
      [(_ (label <label>:str)
          (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
                     #:defaults ([(<object> 1) null]))) ; (HERE)
       #'(bag <label>
              (list <object>.result ...))]))
;; ?: attribute contains non-list value
;;   value: #f


;; IMPLEMENTATION THREE
;; DESC: it won't fail when not using syntax-class attributes
;; UNCOMMENT TO TEST
#;(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
      #:datum-literals (label objects)
      [(_ (label <label>:str)
          (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
                     #:defaults ([(<object> 1) null])))
       #'(bag <label>
              (list <object> ...))])) ; (HERE)
;; name: unbound identifier


;; IMPLEMENTATION FOUR
;; DESC: it works, but I find it ugly
;; UNCOMMENT TO TEST
#;(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
      #:datum-literals (label objects)
      [(_ (label <label>:str)
          (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)))
       #`(bag <label>
              (list #,@(if (attribute <object>)
                           #'(<object>.result ...)
                           #'())))]))


(module+ test (require rackunit)

(check-equal?
  (parse-bag
    (label "Biscuits")
    (objects (object (name "Cookie"))
             (object (name "Brownie"))))

  (bag "Biscuits"
        (list (object "Cookie")
              (object "Brownie"))))

(check-equal?
  (parse-bag (label "Sweets"))
  (bag "Sweets" '()))

)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two classes of strategies to fix "attribute value is false" errors:

1. Put defaults or alternatives so that the attribute is never false.

   (a) Using [`~optional`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28elem._%28pattern-link._%28%7E7eoptional._h%29%29%29) with `#:defaults`

   (b) Using [`~or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28elem._%28pattern-link._%28%7E7eor%2A._h%29%29%29), possibly with [`~parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._%7E7eparse%29%29)

   (c) Using a syntax-class with multiple patterns
2. Deal with the attribute being false in the body.

   (a) Using [`unsyntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fqqstx..rkt)._unsyntax))) and [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#(form._((quote._%7E23%7E25kernel)._if)))

   (b) Using [`~?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt)._%7E7e%7E3f)))

#### 1 (a)

Implementations 2 and 3 in the question, as well as the code in Zoé's answer, all use [`~optional`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28elem._%28pattern-link._%28%7E7eoptional._h%29%29%29) with `#:defaults`, so they all are attempts to fix it with 1 (a).

Zoé's answer shows a correct use of this. The main point is that if you use an attribute like `<object>.result`, you need to specify a default for `<object>.result`, not just `<object>`.

However, one downside to this comes if there are multiple attributes in the `obj-exp` class that you need to use. That would require you to specify a default for each one:

```
(~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
           #:defaults ([(<object>.result 1) null]
                       [(<object>.x 1) null]))
```

#### 1 (b)

If you use multiple attributes from a syntax class, such as `<object>.result`, `<object>.x`, `<object>.y`, `<object>.z`, etc, then 1 (a) would require you to specify a default for each one separately. To avoid that, instead of writing this:

```
(~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
           #:defaults ([(<object>.result 1) null]
                       [(<object>.x 1) null]
                       [(<object>.y 1) null]
                       [(<object>.z 1) null]))
```

You can use [`~or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28elem._%28pattern-link._%28%7E7eor%2A._h%29%29%29) and [`~parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._%7E7eparse%29%29) like this:

```
(~or (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
     (~and (~seq) (~parse (<object>:obj-exp ...) null)))
```

#### 1 (c)

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class maybe-objects
  #:datum-literals (objects)
  [pattern (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)]
  [pattern (~seq) #:with (<object>:obj-exp ...) null])
```

#### 2 (a) and (b)

Implementation 4 in the question uses [`unsyntax-splicing`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fqqstx..rkt%29._unsyntax-splicing%29%29) and [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#(form._((quote._%7E23%7E25kernel)._if))), so it's an example of 2 (a):

```
#,@(if (attribute <object>)
       #'(<object>.result ...)
       #'())
```

However, as you noted, this looks kind of ugly. And it also has another problem. If this itself were under an ellipsis, this breaks down because ellipses don't carry their effects inside a [`#,`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fqqstx..rkt)._unsyntax))) or [`#,@`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fqqstx..rkt%29._unsyntax-splicing%29%29).

That's why [`~?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt)._%7E7e%7E3f))) exists for 2 (b). Instead of using `#,@(if ....)`, you can use:

```
(~? (<object>.result ...) ())
```

That doesn't quite work, but this variant of it does:

```
(~? (list <object>.result ...) (list))
```

Using that in a variation on implementation 4:

```
(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:datum-literals (label objects)
    [(_ (label <label>:str)
        (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)))
     #`(bag <label>
            (~? (list <object>.result ...) (list)))]))
```

Comment: Awesome! Now I know a lot of different ways to tackle some syntax-parse issues, using `~?` and `~parse`, which I didn't knew about before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

When using `#:defaults`, you need to specify the attribute:

```
(~optional <object>:obj-exp ... #:defaults ([(<object>.result 1) null]))
```

### Complete code:

```
(define-syntax (parse-bag stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
      #:datum-literals (label objects)
      [(_ (label <label>:str)
          (~optional (objects <object>:obj-exp ...)
                     #:defaults ([(<object>.result 1) null]))) ; + attribute here
       #'(bag <label>
              (list <object>.result ...))])) ; now it works!
```

Another way would be to move the ellipsis usage to the syntax-class, as in this question: [A splicing syntax class that matches an optional pattern and binds attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383613/a-splicing-syntax-class-that-matches-an-optional-pattern-and-binds-attributes)